# How to run an app on memory in a untrusted computer?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, application

I'm having complex situation where I would like to run an application without adding into Hard Drive to prevent unauthorized copying during a demo.

Is there are any tool on Linux that I can use to run application on memory?

Comment: If it's a demonstration why not add your application to a Live instance and run directly from (say) a USB stick?

Comment: Also, if you're running it in an alien system you cannot trust it's not compromised such a way it inconspicuously copies everything which is being run to a certain location.

Comment: Is you question "how do I stop an entrusted device copying my program/data?" OR "how can I run a program without copying it to (another) secondary storage device?" OR is it something different?

Comment: Why do you think that you have to copy to any particular hard-disk? You can use any disk or SSD, such as a USB attached secondary-storage device (usb-harddisk or usb-ssd (often called a thumb drive)).